# Add an image at end of video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add an image at the end of the video for 1 second.
There are 2 images image1 is for square type videos and image2 is for vertical (full screen videos).

I'm using php on my server. i can create a separate videos each images and when i try to add it to the videos it fails. i tried many commands and everything failed.

used this command to convert image to video

```
exec('ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image1.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4');
```

even tried this solution [FFMPEG add image at the end of a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532118/ffmpeg-add-image-at-the-end-of-a-video?rq=1) for it does not create any output.

anybody help me with this condition 
my `ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Comment: Need to see info about your inputs. Run this command: `ffmpeg -n -i square.mp4 -i vertical.mp4 -i square.png -i vertical.png`. This will provide useful info about the inputs and your `ffmpeg` version. This info is required to provide an answer that you can copy and paste. Copy the **complete** log from that command. [Edit] your question and paste the complete log into your question. Ignore the `At least one output file must be specified error` in the log.